# How to rectify the error when generating a saliency map

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm attempting to create a function to generate the saliency map.  This is the code.

```
def do_salience(image, model, label, prefix):
    img = cv2.imread(image)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img= cv2.resize(img,(300,300))/255.0
    img= np.expand_dims(img,axis=0)

num_classes= 2

expected_output= tf.one_hot([label]* img.shape[0],num_classes)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape: 
    inputs = tf.cast(img,tf.float32)
    tape.watch(inputs)
    predictions = model(inputs)

loss= tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(
    expected_output,predictions
)

print(predictions)
gradients= tape.gradient(loss,inputs)
grayscale_tensor = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(gradients), axis=-1)

normalized_tensor = tf.cast(
  255
  * (grayscale_tensor-tf.reduce_min(grayscale_tensor))
  / (tf.reduce_max(grayscale_tensor)-tf.reduce_min(grayscale_tensor)),
  tf.uint8,
 )

normalized_tensor= tf.squeeze(normalized_tensor)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(normalized_tensor, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

This part is to superimpose the saliency map with the original image

```
gradient_color = cv2.applyColorMap(normalized_tensor.numpy(),
                                  cv2.COLORMAP_HOT)
gradient_color = gradient_color/255.0
super_imposed = cv2.addWeighted(img,0.5,gradient_color,0.5,0.0)

salient_image_name = prefix + image
normalized_tensor = tf.expand_dims(normalized_tensor, -1)
normalized_tensor = tf.io.encode_jpeg(normalized_tensor, 
                       quality=100, format='grayscale')
writer = tf.io.write_file(salient_image_name, normalized_tensor)
```

Next, proceeding to the 'generating of saliency maps with untrained model' stage,

```
model.load_weights('0_epochs.h5')
do_salience('cat1.jpg', model, 0, 'epoch0_salient')
do_salience('cat2.jpg', model, 0, 'epoch0_salient')
do_salience('catanddog.jpg', model, 0, 'epoch0_salient')
do_salience('dog1.jpg', model, 1, 'epoch0_salient')
do_salience('dog2.jpg', model, 1, 'epoch0_salient')
```

After loading the code, I'm thrown with an error,

[image: error]

I believe there is a mistake in the code where it's superimposing the saliency map. How to rectify it?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve grad-cam?

Comment: you're kind of right.

Comment: Check my answer on this, it may what you need. Let us know. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66189774/9215780

Comment: thank you for the link. I'm actually stuck in                                              
   gradient_color = cv2.applyColorMap(normalized_tensor.numpy(cv2.COLORMAP_HOT)
gradient_color = gradient_color/255.0
super_imposed = cv2.addWeighted(img,0.5,gradient_color,0.5,0.0)