# RuntimeError: tf.gradients is not supported when eager execution is enabled. Use tf.GradientTape instead

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

Hi I was trying to reproduce results from this link
[Keras CNN Chexpert](https://www.kaggle.com/code/estebvac/chexpert-keras-base/notebook)

and I encounter this error `RuntimeError: tf.gradients is not supported when eager execution is enabled. Use tf.GradientTape instead` when I was running this line of code

```
grads = K.gradients(class_output, last_conv_layer.output)[0]
```

However when I change to this line of code

```
grads = tf.GradientTape(class_output, last_conv_layer.output)[0]
```

I get this error " ----> 2 grads = tf.GradientTape(class_output, last_conv_layer.output)[0]
TypeError: 'GradientTape' object is not subscriptable".

Appreciate it if someone can guide me in correcting this.

below is a snippet of the codes

```
# get the first image of the testing dataset
x = test_generator[0][0]
preds = model.predict(x)

preds = y_pred_keras[1,:]
class_idx = np.argmax(preds)
class_output = model.output[:, class_idx]
#import the last convolutional layer of the model, this depends on the model
last_conv_layer = model.get_layer("conv5_block16_concat")

# grads = K.gradients(class_output, last_conv_layer.output)[0] 
grads = tf.GradientTape(class_output, last_conv_layer.output)[0]
pooled_grads = K.mean(grads, axis=(0, 1, 2))
iterate = K.function([model.input], [pooled_grads, last_conv_layer.output[0]])
pooled_grads_value, conv_layer_output_value = iterate([x])
for i in range(1024):
    conv_layer_output_value[:, :, i] *= pooled_grads_value[i]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I manage to find a guide to work around and implement the tensorflow v2 codes for the gradCAM, via these 2 links. Hope it helps anyone facing the same issue.

[Pyimage GradCam](https://pyimagesearch.com/2020/03/09/grad-cam-visualize-class-activation-maps-with-keras-tensorflow-and-deep-learning/)

[How to implement Grad-CAM on a trained network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66182884/how-to-implement-grad-cam-on-a-trained-network)